# starting a gui application from php web page

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php

I am new to php but I think I understand this much. The apache client can't access the X server, which results in it being unable to open a gui on command. I have gotten my php to move files around on my pc from a button click on a html page, but I need it to open something that requires a gui, like nautilus. Is there any way to do this? And yes, I want the application opened on the host server.

I am attempting to make a gui that launches a variety of different apps from a html page. The page is in a custom renderer. I am using html since I have the most experience in it and need the gui to be made soon.

Comment: Hi and welcome! So you want a PHP web page to open a GUI software application (the Nautilus file manager) on the machine which hosts the web server. But why do you want this? Please [edit] your post and tell us, then ping me in a comment reply.

Comment: I do not know how to ping you in a comment reply but I edited the post

Comment: Welcome.   Keep asking questions.  That's what builds our community.    Meanwhile, to your dilemma, I can only quote Microsoft:  "That's not a bug; that's a feature."   It would invite all sorts of abuse for web servers to operate at the file system level, which would be required to execute the xstart command - think of Apache as like a sandbox in that sense.   Plus, once xstart begins it is very console-based.  There is no hooks to redirect the output to sockets.   So I believe your best option is to find hooks into databases or whatever the GUI would have done, and present it in HTML.

Comment: You pinged him by making a comment.  It sends out emails to let us know about updates to posts where we have participated.  So you did it just right.

Comment: ok thank you and yes again I need it to start in the server not the client. This webpage will not even be viewable from outside the server. Only the person on the server itself can see the html gui and subsequently the program would start on the server, not any client pc

Comment: Precisely.  But whatever your X GUI can do, you can probably do in HTML.  Like connecting to databases, etc.  Of course, that means you will need to lay out the screens.  But like I always say:  The best part of programming is that you can control anything.  The worst part is that you have to control everything.  ;-)   Have a nice night.